# check if some values of an array exist in the key of another object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's there is an array & object.

```
getSelectedArrValue = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
getSelectedObjValue = {firstName: 'John', lastName: null, birthYear: 1980 };
```

`getSelectedArrValue` & `getSelectedObjValue` is generated by some another events and dynamically changed based on the event. Now, I want if the values of `getSelectedArrValue` exist in the object, `getSelectedObjValue` and any of them is `null` in the object, it'll show in console which one is null; something like this:

```
console.log('OOPS! ' + ____ + ' is null.');
```

So, the output for those selected data:

`OOPS! lastName is null.`

As, the values of the variable are generated continuously & dynamically based on some changed state(event), these can be happened:

```
getSelectedArrValue = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
getSelectedObjValue = {firstName: 'null', lastName: null, birthYear: 1985 };
```

Output:

```
OOPS! firstName is null.
OOPS! lastName is null.
```

Some more example:

```
getSelectedArrValue = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
getSelectedObjValue = {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Hussy', birthYear: 1990 };
```

Output:

```
Everything is fine!
```

Another example:

```
getSelectedArrValue = ['phoneNumber', 'address'];
getSelectedObjValue = {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Hussy', birthYear: 1990 };
```

Output:

```
Everything is fine!
```

Please, help me to write the jQuery code to achieve those functionality. I guess, the js will be something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < getSelectedArrValue.length; i++) {
   if (getSelectedArrValue[i] in getSelectedObjValue.i) {
      // I am not sure that 'i' in object (getSelectedObjValue.i) works or not at here. 
      // Is there any other method to access value/key of object?
      if (getSelectedObjValue.i === null) {
         console.log('OOPS! ' + getSelectedArrValue[i] + ' is null.');
      } else {
         console.log('Everything is fine!');
      }
   }
}
```

But, I can't write in correct way as I am not good enough in jQuery. That's why I ask for help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hasOwnProperty` check on your object, for each array value, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < getSelectedArrValue.length; i++) {
      if (!getSelectedObjValue.hasOwnProperty(getSelectedArrValue[i]) || getSelectedObjValue[getSelectedArrValue[i]] === null) {
         console.log('OOPS! ' + getSelectedArrValue[i] + ' is null.');
      } else {
         console.log('Everything is fine!');
      }
}
```

EDIT: If you want the code to output everything is fine in case the object does NOT have a property in the array, you need to modify your if condition as such:

`getSelectedObjValue.hasOwnProperty(getSelectedArrValue[i]) && getSelectedObjValue[getSelectedArrValue[i]] === null`